# How to save mp3 file to in phone programmatically using Objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, download, mp3

I have 4 ringtones in my iOS app. I want to provide the facility to download these files to the user.  As files are very small. I have kept them in my resource folder.I want to save like as we save out photos to photo library.

Went thought most of the Stackoverflow questions nobody uses it to save as mp3. Is there any known issue I can face if I do it?

Comment: you want to download files and save them locally?

Comment: Check the below my code. let me any clarifications.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me but m not getting the option to set that music file as ringtone..if possible let me know the procedure to set ringtone after saving the sound.

Comment: We can't Programatically set ringtones. Apple not allow this type of features.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code. use this code we can save Resource Folder audio file to Library.

```
 UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audiofile" ofType:@"mp3"], nil, nil, nil);
```

We can save Audio files Like this.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you for guidance..it worked but the new problem is m not able to set that sound as my ringtone in iphone

Comment: We can't Programatically set ringtones. Apple not allow this type of features.

Comment: is it possible to store music file in iOS native music app from our app?

Comment: @PramodTapaniya No. Apple don't have this feature.